# Appending string to all urls within a table with jquery

Tags: jquery

We have a hidden product table that gets revealed when folks are ready to buy products from our website.  There are several call to action buttons on each page that reveal this and we are trying to figure out which is most effective.

The idea is to append extra values to each url in that table to indicate which CTA was used:

```
we want to change
http://mydomain.com/buy.htm?pid=thah151

adding &btn=top
http://mydomain.com/buy.htm?pid=thah151&btn=top
```

The urls are contained within a table:

```
<div id="buygrid">
some general copy
<table class="prodgrid">
    <tr class="byrow"><td>other cells</td><td class="bybtn"><a href="http://mydomain.com/buy.htm?pid=thah151" class="button1">Buy This One</a></td></tr>
    <tr>more similar rows</tr>
</table>
more general copy
</div>
```

Each product page has a different number of rows.

I read up on jQuery's each function, which seemed promising, but could get it to work for this.  Not sure if I was targeting the wrong classes/ids (I tried a lot of combos) or if each doesn't parse through a table or ...

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: You haven't posted your code that we're trying to help you fix ;)

Comment: I have tried so many different ideas that failed, I am not sure which if any would be fixable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a same class for them and do as the following:

```
//assuming all a tags have button1 class to which you want to change
//or change button1 to what you target as the selector
$('.button1').attr('href',function(){
   return this.href + "&btn=top";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have same href values for all anchors, you can use:

```
 $('.byrow a').attr('href',$('.byrow a').attr('href')+'&btn=top');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TS7vx/)**

Comment: Not sure of your "same href values" reference.  While the basic url is the same, the pid=string will be different in each row.